# why can't I change object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I made a mistake with the age property on these objects and when I try to reassign different values later, it won't change it at all.

I want this to work with the `Object.create` Method. What should I do to fix this?

```js
var personProto = {
  calculateAge: function() {
    console.log(2019 - this.yearOfBirth)
  },
  fullName: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.lastName)
  }
}

var sam = Object.create(personProto, {
  name: { value: "samuel" },
  yearOfBirth: { value: 1092 },
  lastName: { value: "max" },
  job: { value: "developer" }
});

sam.yearOfBirth = 1992;

sam.calculateAge(); // 927
```

`console.log(sam.calculateAge());` is giving me 927 assuming yearsOfBirth is still 1092 even if I changed it to 1992 and the output was supposed to be 27.

Comment: Because the property descriptors that you use default to `writable: false`.

Comment: See [Object.defineProperties()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

Answer (score 8):

By default, properties assigned using `Object.create` are not writable. Attempting to write to a non-writable property is a silent error in JavaScript - one of many reasons to use Strict Mode.

Here is your code again, but in Strict Mode:

```js
'use strict';

var personProto = {

        calculateAge:function(){
            console.log(2019 -this.yearOfBirth)
        },
        fullName:function(){
            console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.lastName)
        }
    }

    var sam = Object.create(personProto, {
        name:{value:'samuel'}, 
        yearOfBirth:{value:1092}, 
        lastName:{value:'max'},
        job:{value:'developer'}
    });

    sam.yearOfBirth = 1992;

    console.log(sam.calculateAge());
    927
```

Notice that it now fires an error and tells you exactly what's wrong.

To fix this, just make the properties writable.

```js
'use strict';

var personProto = {

        calculateAge:function(){
            console.log(2019 -this.yearOfBirth)
        },
        fullName:function(){
            console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.lastName)
        }
    }

    var sam = Object.create(personProto, {
        name:{value:'samuel',writable:true}, 
        yearOfBirth:{value:1092,writable:true}, 
        lastName:{value:'max',writable:true},
        job:{value:'developer',writable:true}
    });

    sam.yearOfBirth = 1992;

    console.log(sam.calculateAge());
    927
```

Comment: "silent error". Yet another great JS design. *Slow clap*.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) uses [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), and the `writable` attribute defaults to `false` when you don't specify it.

I would recommend to drop the second argument entirely, and instead use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create the properties on the new object:

```
var sam = Object.assign(Object.create(personProto), {
    name: 'samuel',
    yearOfBirth: 1092,
    lastName: 'max',
    job: 'developer',
});
```